# How to block <script> in body before load of document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Can I block scripts in body of html-page before they run? How?

The main problem is when I put my page on host, I see line-banner in the head of my site...and I sent XMLHttpRequest to page and found that this banner was made by , which automatically was generated by hosting serve)))

I will be very glad for help!

Comment: What do you mean block? What have you tried?

Comment: The right way is to place the script at the end of the document, or wrap your functions in `$(document).ready()` and place them anywhere.

Comment: sure...just disable scripts in your browser

Comment: I would think you'd have to scrub the <script tags out before they get into the html.

Comment: Is this for a site you own or one you're visiting? If you own it, simply modify the markup to not include the `<script>` in question. If it's for one you're visiting, then this may be a better fit for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oh, no...:(((the theory of placement of scripts in docs I know. The main problem is when I put my page on host, I see line-banner in the head of my site...and I sent XMLHttpRequest to page and found that this banner was made by <scrip>, which automatically was generated by hosting serve)))

Comment: @MamekoMikhail Some hosting providers use ad injection rather than charging a recurring fee for their source of revenue. It's likely mentioned as a requirement in their Terms of Service you agreed to. So, to properly remove the `<script>` and ad from your pages, you'll want to find a different host that doesn't use ads. There are hosts that offer free or cheap plans for smaller servers.

Comment: I thought, I can stop it before loading...ok, thanks for answers

Comment: [Good free hosting](http://www.000webhost.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to stop XSS attacks?

Using the razor engine, as long as you use

```
@Model.CommentText
```

It should take care of HTML encoding for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to defer loading for page speed performance reasons then google would have you do something like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function downloadJSAtOnload() {
  var element = document.createElement("script");
  element.src = "deferred_script.js";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;

</script>
```

Comment: The main problem is when I put my page on host, I see line-banner in the head of my site...and I sent XMLHttpRequest to page and found that this banner was made by <scrip>, which automatically was generated by hosting serve)))

Comment: Well, you gotta pay for hosting i guess.